# How do I echo an array to string conversion from JSON in a foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to pass an array into a database but i'm getting a notice and the echo is not working to print out the string I want.

> Notice: Array to string conversion on line 7 ( echo $item; )

How do I capture the data being sent into a database?

Where the arrays are sent by author and their books.
e.g.

> [{"name":"Book1","books":["Book1.1"]},{"name":"Book2","books":["Book2.1","Book2.2"]}]

This is next.php where the data is being passed and not being echoed.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);

$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['arr']), true);

foreach($data as $item){
   echo $item;
   // insert to db
}

?>
```

The alert is giving me the return data from next.php in the sendToServer function (see snippet).

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Full code in the snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    <!-- #main {
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    -->
  </style>
</head>

    <body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>Add or Remove text boxes with jQuery</h1>
        <div class="my-form">
<!--            <form action="next.php" method="post">-->
                <button onclick="addAuthor()">Add Author</button>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div id="addAuth"></div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<!--            </form>-->
        </div>

        <div id="result"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var authors = 0;

        function addAuthor() {
        authors++;
            var str = '<br/>' + '<div id="auth' + authors + '">' + '<input type="text" name="author" id="author' + authors + '" placeholder="Author Name:"/>' + '<br/>' + '<button onclick="addMore(\'auth' + authors + '\')" >Add Book</button>' + '</div>';
            $("#addAuth").append(str);
        }

        var count = 0;

        function addMore(id) {
            count++;
            var str = 
            '<div id="bookDiv' + count + '">' 
                + '<input class="' + id + '" type="text" name="book' + id + '" placeholder="Book Name"/>' 
                + '<span onclick="removeDiv(\'bookDiv' + count + '\')">Remove</span>'
            + '</div>';
            $("#" + id).append(str);
        }
        
        function removeDiv(id) {
            $("#" + id).slideUp(function() {
                $("#" + id).remove();
            });
        }
        function submit() {
            var arr = [];
            for (i = 1; i <= authors; i++) {
                var obj = {};
                obj.name = $("#author" + i).val();
                obj.books = [];
                $(".auth" + i).each(function() {
                var data = $(this).val();
                    obj.books.push(data);
                });
                arr.push(obj);
            }
            sendToServer(arr);
            //$("#result").html(JSON.stringify(arr));
        }

        function sendToServer(data) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    arr: JSON.stringify(data)
                },
                url: "next.php",
                success: function(data) {
                        alert(data);
                }
            });
            
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In order to print `$item` on server side you can try `print_r` instead of `echo`

Comment: how do I insert them into a database? print_r($item); works.

Comment: `print_r` is an option, but `var_dump` is my prefered one...

Comment: Which DB do you use? Any framework for php?

Comment: mysql as for frameworks only bootstrap

Comment: @learningbyexample please check my answer. I also have given an example to push data into database for your ease.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting Notice: Array to string conversion on line 7 ( echo $item; ) because you are going to print array.
You can't print array whereas you can do a string so.
To do like that use something like this.

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);

$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['arr']), true);

for ($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    echo "Name: ".$data[$i]['name']. "<br/>";
    echo "Books: ";
    foreach($data[$i]['books'] as $book){
        echo $book . " ";
    }
    echo "...............<br/>";    

    // insert to db example
    $sql="INSERT INTO author(id, name) VALUES (NULL, '".$data[$i]['name']."')";
    //execute query and get last insert id
    //$author_id=last insert id
    foreach($data[$i]['books'] as $book){
        $sql="INSERT INTO author_books(id, author_id, book_name) VALUES (NULL,'$author_id', '$book')";
        //execute query
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: I think you're missing a for loop?

Comment: @Terminus It's possible both way.

Comment: `$_POST['arr']` is an array of objects. The first "level"s key will be 0,1,2, etc... You won't be able to access the inner "name" and "books" keys with your `$key` variable

Comment: @Terminus you are right, It's indexed array, then associative. up for your comment.

Comment: @AhmadAsjad Notice: indefined variable: author_id

Comment: @learningbyexample I gave you an example to do like that. Now it's upto you. How can I know that what's your database table structure. It's only possible if you provide the database structur as well. Another solution is that I'll provide you the database structure as well for the same.

Answer (score 2):

**This is what you have form POST:**

```
    [
        {
            "name":"Book1",
            "books": [
                "Book1.1"
            ]
        },{
            "name":"Book2",
            "books": [
                "Book2.1",
                "Book2.2"
            ]
        }
    ]
```

**To read the data using a foreach you need to do:**

```
foreach($data as $item) {
    echo "Name: " . $item["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Books: " . implode(", ", $item["books"]) . "<br>";

    // Other way..

    echo "Name: " . $item["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Books: <br>";
    foreach($book as $item["books"])
        echo $book . "<br>";
}
```

By this foreach you can manipulate your data and build your INSERT statement to input data to database.

Comment: I don't know if your foreach is correct (second one) `foreach($book in $item["books"])` where you put "in" I tried to put "as" `foreach($book as $item["books"])` but it gives me a notice: undefined variable book and then a warning in later arrays invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Oh thats true, i programs in a lot of languages sometimes i do such thing. Thanks.